# why printf behaves differently when we try to print float as a hexadecimal?

Tags: c, precision

I tried to print float as a hexadecimal and go output differently every time. 
What is the reason for this.

Also:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int 
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    float f;
    f = 9.0;
    printf("binary f=0x%X, f=%f, f=%e\n", f, f, f);

    return 0;
}
// output: 
// binary f=0xAA7EDE38, f=9.000000, f=9.000000e+00
// binary f=0xB23E34A8, f=9.000000, f=9.000000e+00
```

why is it so?

Comment: Try looking in almost any C book in the chapter on printf.

Comment: Using mismatching format specifier and argument will lead to *undefined behavior*. And if you have UB (Undefined Behavior) then your whole program is ill-formed and invalid.

Comment: `%A` instead of `0x%X` ?  What kind of output do you expect?

Comment: `%X` expext a integral number from type (`unsigned`) `int`, or a smaller (such as `char`) type. Everything else is UB.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY   I expect a binary representation of floating point numbers. Thanks.

Comment: like [this](http://ideone.com/JRJOqb)